# PrimeNg multiselect dropdown breaks the default tab key navigation for each field

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, primeng

Currently I'm using angular, Primeng, Typescript and css. I have added primeNg multiselect dropdown for my forms when I go using tab key to multiselect dropdown, after press space it's open and I go to the inside the multiselect dropdown using only keyboard after select option using enter key and again press tab key for go to next field but didn't focus to next field It's focus on the browser menu. I think default tab navigation behaviour is break.

I use this method to fixed that but it didn't work

```
(keydown.enter)="multiSelect1.focus()"
```

*this "multiSelect1" is reference of my multiselect dropdown

I use this directive for solve issue this one also not working

```
import {AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMultiselectFocus]'
})
export class MultiselectFocusDirective implements AfterViewInit{

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2 ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const multiselectDropdown = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.p-dropdown:not(.p-disabled).p-focus');

    if (multiselectDropdown) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(multiselectDropdown, 'tabindex', '0');
    }
  }
```

How to I fix this issue?